# How to make babel output classes as named functions?

Tags: typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-loader

Right now it translates `class X { ... }` to `var X = function X(...) { ... }`, how do I make it output it as `function X (...) { ... }`?

Comment: Why would you want it if I may ask? Classes are not hoisted - if your ES6 code depends on it, it's wrong.

Comment: Mainly because if you call `function Y` that creates `class X` but the function is defined before the class, it will error out.

Comment: @OneOfOne This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/140350). You're asking how to do one thing (change how Babel transpiles something), when the actual problem you're trying to solve is something else ("if you call function Y that creates class X but the function is defined before the class, it will error out"). Ask about the latter, not the former.

Comment: @OneOfOne As it should (if you mean the function is _called_, not defined before the class).

Comment: @destoryer and that's why I want it to output `function X() {...}`, because that way the class will always be there regardless.

Comment: That's not how real classes work though. If you do this, all your code would break when you stop using Babel. `class X {}` is essentially identical to `let X = class X {};`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between function declarations and ES6 classes is that function declarations are hoisted:

```
console.log(Foo); // Foo
function Foo() {}
```

And classes are in temporal dead zone:

```
console.log(Foo); // ReferenceError
class Foo {}
```

It would be incorrect to transpile a class to function declaration, and the correct function representation of ES6 class is:

```
const Foo = function Foo() {};
```

Since there is no `const` in ES5, Babel transpiles it to `var`, also tries to mimic temporal dead zone where possible when [respective transform](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-block-scoping) is enabled.